# Large Dataset Overloading Memory Using Phalcon Cache

Tags: phalcon

I'm working on a project that requires me to work with and process large amounts of data. I'm using phalcon's caching system to establish data 'checkpoints' to ensure that I only process data when I need to.

PHP maximum memory allocation is 2GB, and I've made arrangements so that the data I attempt to cache doesn't exceed this, but I'm having problems and am continually exceeding the memory limit.

I did some playing around with the memory_get_usage() function and memory_get_peak_usage() function and determined that my peak memory basically doubles when I try to save results to the cache.

My initial thought is that this is occurring because Phalcon has to open the file handle where the data is being stored which quickly becomes large as soon as the data is added to it.

**Is this off track?**
If so, is there any way to write to cache files without necessarily opening the handle?

If there isn't any good way around this I guess I'll just limit my data sets to account for the file handle space when caching.

**Edit:** More details for clarity.

- Peak memory allocation (when running without phalcon cache save): 565.9 MB
- W/ the cache save I get the following error:
  `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1015021568) (tried to allocate 161480754 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tda_v2\app\library\analyzer\analyzerCache.php on line 131`
- How could saving 565.9 MB of data to a cache file result in overflowing a 2GB limit?

Comment: Is the data in a Phalcon Resultset object? If so, you don't want to cache the result before processing, just use the Resultset object http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#model-resultsets

Comment: No, the data is an array of objects of a class I defined. The idea is that I want to manipulate a dataset in several stages, checkpointing the data into a cache at each stage to avoid duplicate processing when unnecessary.